# Allocating words from a string separated by spaces to a variable? C++ [qt]

Tags: c++, string, qt, qstring

I just wanted to know what the technical term for allocating words from a string separated by spaces to a variable is called so I can look up a tutorial for it. Any terms, links, or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Google: _"parsing text c++ site:stackoverflow.com"_

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like:

```
QString lineText = "some sample words";

QStringList tokens= lineText.split(" ",QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

You can do whatever you like with the words in the tokens list.